# jqGrid gridComplete:- getRowData - get row cell value from array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

> Please - need syntax for setting variables from jqGrid getRowData
>   property

Looping thru rows - just need to pull the ID and Phrase column values into variables

```
gridComplete: function () {
  var allRowsInGrid = $('#list').jqGrid('getRowData');
  for (i = 0; i < allRowsInGrid.length; i++) {
    pid = allRowsInGrid[i].ID;
    vPhrase = allRowsInGrid[i].Phrase;
    vHref = "<a href='#' onclick='openForm(" + pid + ", " + vPhrase + ")'>View</a>";
  }
},
```

Was able to get ID easy enough with getDataIDs :-)

Need help with getting specific column values for pid and vPhrase for i

Cheers

Comment: What are you doing with this array once you have it?  Depending on your requirements `rowattr:` might be more efficient.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Try this:

```
var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) 
{
    var rowId = ids[i];
    var rowData = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);

    console.log(rowData.Phrase);
    console.log(rowId);
}
```

Please Note: If your goal is to add a link to cell which calls a javascript method you can achieve this by using `formatter` like given below, formatter  should be added to colModel like you add other column properties like name,index,width,align etc, so you can avoid the iteration over row data

```
formatter: function(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {

    return  "<a href='#' onclick='openForm(" 
            + rowObject.ID + ", " 
            + rowObject.Phrase 
            + ")'>View</a>"; 
      }
```

Comment: A note: this works, but only if the value you need is in a grid column. You can hide the column if you don't want to display the value, but it has to be there.

Answer (score 4):

This is what I use when I want to get Data by `RowID` for specific `Cell`.

```
var selRow = jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('getGridParam','selarrrow');  //get selected rows
for(var i=0;i<selRow.length;i++)  //iterate through array of selected rows
{
    var ret = jQuery("#list10").jqGrid('getRowData',selRow[i]);   //get the selected row
    name = ret.NAME;  //get the data from selected row by column name
    add = ret.ADDRESS;
    cno = ret.CONTACTNUMBER
    alert(selRow[i] +' : ' + name +' : ' + add +' : ' + cno);
}
```