# How to get cell value on gridComplete method

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have try to get cell data on gridComplte event but I am not able to getting a value of cell
so,please suggest me how to get that?

```
gridComplete: function () 
    {
         var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
         alert(ids);
        for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++)
        {
            var rowId = ids[i];
           // var rowData = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
            var cont = jQuery('#list').getCell(rowId, 'SYS');  //SYS is my colNames
            var val = $(cont).val();
            alert(val);
        }
    },
```

Comment: It's not full clear what you need, but probably what you do will be better implemented using [getCol](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285282/jqgrid-gridcomplete-getrowdata-get-row-cell-value-from-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code above, variable "cont" should have the value of 'SYS' column.
Remove the line

```
var val = $(cont).val();
```

Here is the corrected code:

```
gridComplete: function () 
{
     var ids = jQuery("#list").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
     alert(ids);
    for(var i=1;i<=ids.length;i++)
    {
        var rowId = ids[i];
       // var rowData = jQuery('#list').jqGrid ('getRowData', rowId);
        var cont = jQuery('#list').getCell(rowId, 'SYS');  //SYS is my colNames
        alert(cont);
    }
},
```